# Library System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions not loaded on Azure web app

Tags: .net, azure, nuget

Since I added a reference to Azure.Container.Blob on my .net 4.8 web app I had several issues with the libraries used by the package. I managed to solve most of the issues but I am stuck with this one when I try to load a page:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

On compilation there is no issue, and on my local dev server there is no issue as well, even during the load of said pages.

I have this setting in my web.config

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.1" newVersion="4.2.0.1" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Which should be managed by the app but it can't find it as shown on the error page:

```
[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]

[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the dll is not copied into the publish directory by MSBuild, which make the deploy to server not copy it either (as it does not exists).